# PHP for loop stops getting MYSQL table rows after 2 loops

Tags: php, mysql

I have a peculiar problem. I am trying to put rows (which there are 5) from my table **products** into a php array (**$ro**), using a **for loop**. My code succeeds in doing this for the first 2 loops, and acknowledges that there are 5 rows to put in the array. However, **the second row that gets put in my array is actually the third row in my table**, and like I said, after the second loop, my function stops getting rows.

I tested printing my arrays and id's and got the following:

```
1=>Array ( [sku] => JVC200123 [name] => Acme DISC [price] => 1.00 [type] => disc [value] => 700 ) 
2=>Array ( [sku] => GGWP0008 [name] => Preacher [price] => 24.99 [type] => book [value] => 1 ) 
...345
```

What am I missing? Here is the code in question:

```
protected function get_prod($conn1)
{
    $pluck_type = array();
    $objects = array();
    $call_type = 'SELECT id, type FROM products ORDER BY id';
    $type_res = mysqli_query($conn1, $call_type);
    $index = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($type_res)){ 
        $pluck_type[$index] = $row;
        $index++;
    }
    for ($roww = 0; $roww < count($pluck_type); $roww++) {
        $product_type = $pluck_type[$roww]['type'];
        $rowid = $pluck_type[$roww]['id'];
        if($product_type == 'disc')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT p.sku, p.name, p.price, p.type, a.value FROM products AS p INNER JOIN attr_size AS a ON p.id = a.product_id WHERE a.id = '".$rowid."';";
            echo $rowid;
        }
        else if ($product_type == 'book')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT p.sku, p.name, p.price, p.type, a.value FROM products AS p  INNER JOIN attr_weight AS a ON p.id = a.product_id WHERE a.id = '".$rowid."';";
            echo $rowid;
        }
        else if ($product_type == 'furniture')
        {
            $sql = "SELECT p.sku, p.name, p.price, p.type, CONCAT(a.height, 'x', a.width, 'x', a.length) AS value FROM products AS p  INNER JOIN attr_dims AS a ON p.id = a.product_id WHERE a.id = '".$rowid."';";
            echo $rowid;
        }
        $val_res = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql);
        $ro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($val_res);
        print_r($ro);
        $objects[$roww] = $ro; 
    }
    $this->objekt = $objects;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `foreach ($pluck_type as $roww => $row)`?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't think of that.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're seeing all 5 rows printed with `print_r($ro)` but they're not in the `$objects` array?

Comment: Also, learn to use `$array[] =` to push a new value onto an array, rather than incrementing an index yourself.

Comment: When you print the array, the index starts at 1 rather than 0? I don't see how that can happen from this code.

Comment: Are you sure all the items in `products` have matching rows in the appropriate `attr_X` table?

Comment: The function prints out all the id's of my table rows correctly ($rowid).  The array where the table rows are going ($ro) only receives two of my table rows before stopping, and for some reason it skips my second table row in favour of the third row.

Comment: Can there be more than 1 match in the `attr_X` table?

Comment: Try adding `echo $product_type;` and make sure the type is one of those 3.

Comment: Nope. Every attr table only has one matching row per product

Comment: You could combine this all into one query that uses `UNION`, instead of doing a separate query for each product.

Comment: I echoed the $product_type at the end of each loop, and it gave the expected result - disc book book furniture disc

Comment: Add error checking: `$val_res = mysqli_query($conn1, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn1));`

Comment: Weird. I got no error messages. How can that even be possible? Is the problem not in the $val_res? EDIT:  I added error checking to  $ro and I got only this: 1Array ( [sku] => JVC200123 [name] => Acme DISC [price] => 1.00 [type] => disc [value] => 700 ) disc2Array ( [sku] => GGWP0008 [name] => Preacher [price] => 24.99 [type] => book [value] => 1 ) book3

Comment: Try adding `echo mysqli_num_rows($val_res);`

Comment: Also, use `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. It will show `false` if there's no row.

Comment: var_dump gave NULL for the last three rows, and the num_rows echo showed 0 for the same rows.

Comment: So the problem is that there's no matching rows in the `attr_X` tables for those product IDs.

Comment: BTW, why not get the sku, name, and price in the first query. Then you don't need a join in the second query.

Comment: What used to work before was declaring three different number variables, setting them all to 1, and then passing them in the queries to get the appropriate rows (incrementing the variables after each loop). However, this proved unsustainable, as I am printing the array values into bootstrap cards, and then deleting rows from the table based on the selection of said cards.

Comment: Oh my god. I am an idiot. I changed WHERE a.id to WHERE p.id based on your suggestions and it worked. I feel so stupid but thank you so very much! Can you post an answer so you get reputation for patiently helping a rookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing the wrong column in your `WHERE` clauses.

```
WHERE a.id = '".$rowid."';";
```

should be

```
WHERE a.product_id = '".$rowid."';";
```

or

```
WHERE p.id = '".$rowid."';";
```

You could do this all as one query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT p.id, p.sku, p.name, p.price, p.type, a.value 
    FROM products AS p 
    INNER JOIN attr_size AS a ON p.id = a.product_id
    WHERE p.type = 'disc'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.id, p.sku, p.name, p.price, p.type, a.value 
    FROM products AS p  
    INNER JOIN attr_weight AS a ON p.id = a.product_id 
    WHERE p.type = 'book'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.id, p.sku, p.name, p.price, p.type, CONCAT(a.height, 'x', a.width, 'x', a.length) AS value 
    FROM products AS p  
    INNER JOIN attr_dims AS a ON p.id = a.product_id 
    WHERE p.type = 'furniture'
) AS x
ORDER BY x.id
```